# Migrating from Material-UI next to Material-UI v1?

Tags: migration, material-ui

There was a migration guide for `Material-UI v0.x` to `Material-UI next`, I don't see the same for `Material-UI next` to `Material-UI v1`.  Has anyone here already tried to migrate manually?  Is it a simple matter of copy-replace?

Comment: I was using the material ui version "^1.0.0-beta.44" and all I had to do was few copy and pastes and few updates 
you can find those under breaking changes in v1.0.0-rc.0 in here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases

Comment: When I upgraded our app to the v1 release, I took us through each beta release and updated the parts of the app that were breaking changes. It really is the best way to make sure that your usage remains consistent with how the API has changed from the beta releases to the current v1.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mike!